Finding Two Lines for Reflection to Achieve a Specific Point Transformation
I'm working on a geometric problem involving reflections and need help finding two lines. Specifically, I have a point $(x, y)$, and I want to reflect it across two lines such that after both reflections, the point transforms into $(y + 2, x - 2)$.
Here's the problem broken down:

I reflect the point $(x, y)$ across the first line, resulting in some intermediate point $(a, b)$.
Then, I reflect $(a, b)$ across a second line, which should result in the point $(y + 2, x - 2)$.

I'm trying to find the equations of the two lines that will achieve this transformation.
What I’ve Tried:
Initially, I considered reflecting the point $(x, y)$ over the line through the origin with the direction vector $\mathbf{v} = \lambda(1, 1)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. This reflection gives the point $(y, x)$, which swaps the coordinates. However, I realized that reflecting over this line alone isn't sufficient because I need the final transformation to include the translation to $(y + 2, x - 2)$.
I also considered the possibility of using an affine mapping to describe this transformation, but I wasn't able to come up with a solution that satisfied the conditions.

Two reflections yields a direct similarity - if the lines are parallel it's a translation, if not parallel a rotation. Your transformation is not a direct similarity, it's a compound of a reflection and a translation that leaves figures in retrograde orientation.

@RobinSparrow Thanks for the explanation. I had already guessed that achieving the transformation with just two reflections wasn’t possible. It did seem a bit strange based on how the problem was set up. I appreciate the clarification.

No problem - btw if you just wanted to move a single point like that, there are endless pairs of lines you could use to translate or rotate the point to the desired end position. But it would be lines specific to that point, the plane in general would not respect the desired relationship.

You need a single reflection, about the line of equation $y=x-2$. That will give you the desired transformation.

I suppose your point $(x,y)$ is a general point, and you want two fixed reflections, so that after applying them on any such $(x,y)$ the result is always $(y+2,x-2)$. (Note that $(x,y)$ and the final result $(y+2,x-2)$ are both on the same line,  $X+Y=x+y$ in $(X,Y)$ coordinates.)
